# Can any $n$-form on an orientable manifold be written in this way?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

If $M$ is a compact orientable $n$-manifold and $\omega$ is an $n$-form on $M$. If I let $\mu$ be a volume form on $M$, can I say that every other $n$-form on $M$ is a multiple of the volume form and write is as $\omega = f \mu $ where $f$ is a smooth function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; if $M$ has dimension $n$, then $\Omega^\bullet(M):=C^\infty(M)\otimes \wedge^\bullet T^*(M)$ and

$$\operatorname{dim}~\wedge^n T^*(M)=1.$$

The volume form is a basis of $\Omega^n(M)$ and the diff. graded algebra $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ is a $C^\infty(M)$-module.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. By the way, what's the difference between volumn form and the volumn element? I am kind of confused here about them. @Avitus

Comment: I think you should distinguish between $\Lambda^n T^\ast M$ and its space of sections $\Omega^n(M)$. The dimension in your answer is a dimension as a $C^\infty(M)$-module.

Comment: But volumn form is defined for Riemann manifolds, can we define for a general manifold? @Jeremy Daniel

Comment: @Jeremy Daniel yes, notation is a bit sloppy: I modify it. Thank you!  To the OP: volume forms are defined on orientable manifolds. On Riemannian manifolds there is a canonical way to define them.